# Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit = 3 "Workout Session is Not Current" Error?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I have been trying to track down the cause of this error for sometime..when I look at the HealthKit [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkerror.code) for HKError, I do not see any listing for a "Workout Current Error", however `case errorInvalidArgument = 3` so the number matches the error I am looking for, does that necessarily mean that this Workout Session Not Current error is an invalid argument or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`HKError.Code.errorInvalidArgument` (rawValue 3) with message  "Workout session is not current" happens if app is not authorized for HealthKit. App can check that workout object type is authorized before creating session.

```
...
let authorizationStatus = healthStore.authorizationStatus(for: HKWorkoutType.workoutType())
if authorizationStatus != .sharingAuthorized {
    // app is not authorized to write workout to health store
    return
}
session = try HKWorkoutSession(configuration: configuration!)
session!.delegate = self
healthStore.start(session!)
...
```

User can change authorization status in settings or Health app.